# How to store date with milliseconds and sort using collections in java

Tags: java, sorting, date, simpledateformat, comparator

In my use case I would like to store date in an object and sort the object based on date[custom comparator] in java. I tried the following code,

```
    class Tweet implements Comparable<Tweet>{
        int tweetId;
        Date dateTime;

        public Tweet(int tweetId, Date dateTime)
        {
            this.tweetId = tweetId;
            this.dateTime = dateTime;
        }

        public Date getDateTime()
        {
            return dateTime;
        }

        public int getTweetId()
        {
            return tweetId;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Tweet o)
        {
            if (getDateTime() == null || o.getDateTime() == null)
                return 0;
            return getDateTime().compareTo(o.getDateTime());
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationObj
    {
        /** Compose a new tweet. */
        public void postTweet(int userId, int tweetId) {
            Date date = new Date();
            User user;
            Date dTime = new Date();
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                String dateTime = sdf.format(date);
                dTime = sdf.parse(dateTime);
            } catch (ParseException  e)
            {
                ;
            }
            if(!userMap.containsKey(userId))
            {
                user = new User(userId);
                userMap.put(userId, user);
            } else {
                user = userMap.get(userId);
            }
            ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = user.getTweets();
            tweets.add(new Tweet(tweetId, dTime));
        }

     public List<Integer> getNewsFeed(int userId) {
        if(!userMap.containsKey(userId))
        {
            return new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        User user = userMap.get(userId);
        ArrayList<Tweet> newsFeedTweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
        ArrayList<Tweet> userTweets = user.getTweets();
        Set<User> followers = user.getFollowers();
        ArrayList<Tweet> followersTweets = getFollowersTweets(followers);

        newsFeedTweets.addAll(userTweets);
        newsFeedTweets.addAll(followersTweets);

        Collections.sort(newsFeedTweets, new Comparator<Tweet>() {
          public int compare(Tweet o1, Tweet o2) {
            if (o1.getDateTime() == null || o2.getDateTime() == null)
                return 0;
            return o2.getDateTime().compareTo(o1.getDateTime());
          }
        });

        ArrayList<Tweet> newsFeed;
        if(newsFeedTweets.size() > 10)
        {
            newsFeed = new ArrayList<Tweet>(newsFeedTweets.subList(0,10));
        }else {
            newsFeed = newsFeedTweets;
        }

        for(Tweet tweet : newsFeed)
        {
            System.out.println("id "+tweet.getTweetId());
        }
        return getTweetIds(newsFeed);
    }

 }
```

I am trying to store the date with milliseconds after parsing with simple date format.

But it is not working. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

You have quite a bit unnecessary lines in your code which, I assume, left over from the different tries, so it is better to clean it first.

You implemented comparable interface for Tweet class, but instead using compare method from Tweet class you are using another comparator.

```
Collections.sort(newsFeedTweets, new Comparator<Tweet>() {
          public int compare(Tweet o1, Tweet o2) {
            if (o1.getDateTime() == null || o2.getDateTime() == null)
                return 0;
            return o2.getDateTime().compareTo(o1.getDateTime());
          }
        });
```

The code above and Tweet.compare method behaves differently one sorting asc and second one desc. 
 You probably want to use

```
 Collections.sort(newsFeedTweets);
```

instead of inline comparator.

Comment: Yeah. Thats a bug. Thanks. But it is coming in order even after removing the custom comparator. This happens only when I add multiple tweets continuously. So I thought it is not taking milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

> But it is not working. Could someone help me with this?

Most likely you are getting an error here.

```
   try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        String dateTime = sdf.format(date);
        dTime = sdf.parse(dateTime);
    } catch (ParseException  e)
    {
        ;
    }
```

But you are ignoring it in the line `;`.  I suggest you print out the error as a minimum. Replace that line `;` with logging or a call to `System.out.println( e );`

Comment: I am not getting any error. I am trying to get the tweets in sorted order. I am not getting in sorted order. It sorts only seconds not milli seconds. I added one more function for the tweet where I did the sorting.

Comment: @Dany you are got getting an error because you are discarding it. You shouldn't be using the current date by default because that would just hide errors and give you the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: @Dany Date just wraps a long which is the time in milli-seconds.  There is no way to specify you only want to sort by seconds even if you wanted to.

Comment: ah ok. I understand that. But in my use case I want to add the current system time to every tweet and sort it later. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: @Dany yes, just use `new Date()` or `LocalDateTime.now()` in Java 8.  I didn't realise you were parsing a date you just created.  It doesn't produce an error because it doesn't do anything.  You can just delete it. i.e. it's a complicated way of writing `dTime = date;`.

Comment: @Dany what is not working? The order is wrong or what?

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I will try that

Answer (score 1):

In comments you asked for a better way to note the current time on your objects.

The better way is to avoid using the notoriously troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

## java.time

Instead use the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the functionality is [back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further [adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `Instant`

The [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a current moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Generally best to use UTC internally in your business logic, storage, and logging. Apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html), [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)) only where required such as for display to the user.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

On your `Tweet` class, define a member variable like this:

```
Instant whenTweeted;
```

## Strings

The java.time classes use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when parsing/generating Strings to represent date-time values. The `Z` at the end is short for `Zulu` and means “UTC”.

> instant.toString() → 2016-06-18T12:34:56.789Z

## Resolution

Regarding resolution, in Java 8 the current moment is captured only up to milliseconds resolution (up to 3 decimal places of fractional second) because of reliance on a legacy implementation of [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html). In Java 9 the current moment is captured in up to nanosecond resolution (up to 9 decimal places), depending on the ability of your computer hardware clock.

## Sorting

For sorting, define your [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) using the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#compareTo-java.time.Instant-) method built into `Instant`.

## Keep it simple

So no need to parse strings or obtain milliseconds-count-from-[epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) as attempted in the Question. The solution is much simpler than that.

Search Stack Overflow for many more discussions and examples of java.time.

Comment: Thanks Basil. I agree UTC makes more sense. Let me try instant.